# OpsCenter Error: "Unable to start Repair Service. Cluster state was not verified."

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

We are running OpsCenter 5.2.1. When attempting to start repair service, the following message appears in "Event Log":

```
"Unable to start Repair Service. Cluster state was not verified. Make sure all nodes are up, the cluster topology is stable, and all agents are connected."
```

Currently using NetworkTopologyStrategy with 9 node cluster spanning 3 DCs.

Anyone else experience this error?

Comment: Can you add any more information like configuration snippets?

Comment: Can you paste the output of curl `http://<host>:8888/<cluster name>/nodes`